# Image-to-Text Decoder

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract, imagedecoder

I would like to decode the following image into text :
[image]

I already tried to use **Tesseract OCR** for my purpose but I've not been lucky so far.

Here's my code :

```
import pytesseract
import sys
import argparse

try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
from subprocess import check_output


def resolve(path):
    check_output(['C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.9-Q16\convert.exe', path, '-resample', '600', path])
    return pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(path))

if __name__=="__main__":
    argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    argparser.add_argument('path',help = 'image path at OCR')
    args = argparser.parse_args()
    path = args.path
    print('Resolving the image...')
    captcha_text = resolve(path)
    print('Result: ',captcha_text)`
```

Here's the output of my program :

```
C:\Users\Foussy\PycharmProjects\03_Imagedecoder>python main.py C:\Users\Foussy\Pictures\4570502--437826.jpeg
Resolving the image...
Result:
```

It seems my program is unable to decode the picture. I tried to decode images with more "obvious" text and it did it well. I also tried several other examples of this type of captcha without success. What do you recommend me to do ?

The thing is, in the end, I would like to write a program that decodes images like this automatically, so unless there's reliable way to modify the images **automatically** in a way that makes Tesseract compatible with, I don't see any other way to solve this problem. If someone knows a certain library or something... Would be helpful.

Comment: I assume you don't have any training data and aim to get all-purpose solution?

Comment: Yes if possible... The aim here is not to develop my own OCR

Comment: @PiotrRarus-ReinstateMonica have you something in mind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This python library might help:  https://pypi.org/project/captcha-solver/

Example:

```
from captcha_solver import CaptchaSolver

solver = CaptchaSolver('twocaptcha', api_key='2captcha.com API HERE')
raw_data = open('captcha.png', 'rb').read()
print(solver.solve_captcha(raw_data))
```

Comment: If I got this well, I can just submit the captcha and then a human will translate it for me after some time... What I would like is something "automatic" and "instant" but thanks for the recommandation.

Comment: Actually, after several weeks of using a service similar to what was suggested, I can say it is quick enough for my usage. Thanks @Priyanka Khairnar

[check this service](https://pypi.org/project/python-anticaptcha/)